# Retrieve users with same "City" through Get-ADuser

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a way by which I can retrieve a list of AD's only belonging to a particular "City"?

Because, there is a property in SET-ADuser -city, so there must be a way for the reverse also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "City" field is [mapped to an LDAP attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677980(v=vs.85).aspx) called "Locality-Name". The LDAP Display Name for said property is `l` (that's a lowercase L):

```
Get-ADUser "mwood" -Properties l | Select-Object Name,@{Name="City";Expression={$_.l}}
```

It also seems that `Get-ADUser` is able to do the translation itself, so you can use a filter like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq 'CityName'"
```

You could also use an LDAP filter:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(l=CityName)(!(HomeDirectory=*)))"
```

Comment: im sorry to say, but its unfunctional.

Comment: Please be more elaborate than "its unfunctional" if you want qualified help

Comment: A positional parameter could not be found that accepts argument "cityname"

Comment: Without knowing what you changed the command to it's a bit hard to help

Comment: replaced mwood with the city name

Comment: what is  the diff between - 
Get-ADUser "mwood" -Properties l | Select-Object Name,@{Name="City";Expression={$_.l}}

and
Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq 'CityName'"

Comment: The first example finds a user with username "mwood", retrieves his City attribute and shows it (it was an example to show you how City and the `l` attribute was mapped). The second one finds users that have their City set to CityName.

Comment: thnks!

how to add two filters in LDAP filter like

"(!(HomeDirectory=*))" + "City -eq 'CityName'"
????

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties City | Where-Object {$_.City -eq "Dublin"}
```

or

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq 'Dublin'"
```

let me know if either of these work for you