# Active Directory - Dsquery

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008

1.How to get list of users in AD from City X ?
I tried to use:
dsquery user -city X
But there isn't parameter City.

2. How to get list of users with last name starts at "S" ?
   I tried to use:
   dsquery user ls "S*"
   But there isn't parameter Last name.

Any help? Of course only in PowerShell.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872720/retrieve-users-with-same-city-through-get-aduser/31875252#31875252 has something to get you started. Write now it just reads like two code writing requests. Look at how get-aduser works as well as where-object that should be more then enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell, we can use Get-aduser like this:

```
Import-module activedirectory
```

so the answer to question 1 would look something like this:

```
 $users = get-aduser -properties city -filter * | ? {$_.city -like "name of the city"}
```

and the answer to question 2 looks something like this:

```
 $users = get-aduser -properties surname -filter * | ? {$_.surname -like "S*"}
```

Combined looks something like:

```
 $users = get-aduser -properties city,surname -filter * | ? {$_.city -like "name of the city" -and $_.surname -like "S*"}
```

Hopes that helps.

Comment: First, this assumes that RSAT/AD-module is installed. Second, that's quite an inefficient way of using filter.

Comment: $users = get-aduser -properties city -filter {city -like "name of city"}

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions is by using `Get-Aduser` as follow:

```
Import-module activedirectory

# To get Users in city X    
Get-ADUser -filter {city -eq 'X'}

# To get users with last name starts with S:
Get-ADUser -Filter {surname -like 'S*'}
```

Hope it helps